# Buy Windows 7 Home Premium in english language from a european country

Tags: windows-7

I live in Italy and I would like to buy Windows 7 in us english language (need it as a programmer).
The support service of the italian online Microsoft store told me that it is not possible to get it from their store, and suggested me to buy it in the uk store.
I would like to know if the version I get from the uk store is the same I would get from the US, or else if there is any other way to buy the license (and get the iso) for the us version of Windows 7 Home Premium.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version you will get from the UK store is the same as the one from USA. They both have en-US (English -United States) as base language.

Comment: FYI: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/08/9705183.aspx